# Reading in bytes from a struct one at a time

Tags: c, printing, formatting, printf, byte

I have a struct of six 16 bit integers and 1 32 bit integer (16 byte's total) and I'm trying to read in the struct one at a time. Currently I use

```
printf("%.4x %.4x %.4x %.4x %.4x %.4x %.4x\n", );
```

with the 7 struct members as the following parameters.

My output is as following:

```
 0001 0100 0010 0002 0058 0070 464c45
```

And I would like to format it as:

```
01 00 00 01 10 00 02 00  58 00 70 00 45 4c 46 00
```

I've been searching everywhere to try and find out how to properly format it. Any help would be greatly appreciated! thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that your desired output format assumes a little-endian system (or, more pedantically, presents the data in the order the bytes would appear naturally in a little-endian system).  That's not a major problem, but you should be at least vaguely aware of the issue.  The solution posted works nicely and gives the desired result on a little-endian system — you'd have to change the required output (to `00 01 01 00 00 10 00 02 00 58 00 70 00 46 4c 45`) on big-endian systems, or do a lot more work in the presentation code.

Answer (score 1):

You can just move an `unsigned char` pointer over the struct, reading byte for byte (I hope I don't mix things up with C++, getting into *undefined behavior* may happen when doing such things):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct Data {
    int16_t small[6];
    int32_t big;
};

void funky_print(struct Data const * data) {
    unsigned char const * ptr = (unsigned char const *)data;
    size_t i;
    printf("%.2hhx", *ptr);
    ++ptr;
    for (i = 1; i < sizeof(*data); ++i) {
        printf(" %.2hhx", *ptr);
        ++ptr;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct Data d = {{0xA0B0, 0xC0D0, 84, 128, 3200, 0}, 0x1BADCAFE};
    funky_print(&d);
    return 0;
}
```

[(Live here)](http://ideone.com/cJ8LVa)